# Learning qplot (gnuplot)

Tags: linux, gnuplot, graphing

What is a good resource for learning qplot? Or even what is a good qplot reference?

Answer (score 1):

Which qplot do you mean: [the Window's plotter](http://www.qplot.com/) or [Allin Cottrell's gnuplot support tool](http://ricardo.ecn.wfu.edu/~cottrell/qplot/)?

Comment: I mean the gnuplot tool. Thanks for the link. Any more info you have would be great.

Comment: I don't think there is much more than on Cottrell's page.  It doesn't really do much: it just converts x-axis labels to a form gnuplot understands, then renders the graph, passing some extra commands so that the labels are as originally input.  If you're trying to get it to do something more fancy, you'll probably have to write your own gnuplot code.